# Webserver PLC Siemens Javascript, when click, set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu and want to write data to a field when clicked. I have tested it with regular tags but I am having trouble with the syntax when I am testing a tag from a PLC that is named 'mytag' with these '' around it .

In the HTML document, I have to tell the program that the particular tag is both read and write by doing this:

```
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name="webdata".'mytag' -->
'"webdata".mytag' is a tricky name, so I made an alias named 'mytag':
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name="webdata" -->
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='Fortype' Use='"webdata".mytag' -->
```

Here is an example for a typical application of the tag where it works using it:

```
:=mytag: 
<form method="post">
    <input name='mytag' type="text" size=2 />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**The code for setting values by click works with regular tags like this:**

```
$("#id_from_dropdown_menu").click(function() {
   $("#myval").html("10");
});
```

**But the code does not work when I try to use 'mytag', I think it is because of the '' signs.**

```
$("#id_from_dropdown_menu").click(function() {
   $("#mytag").html("10");
});
```

ANY TIPS?

Answer (score 0):

NO worries! Figured it out. Leave post of you get similar problems :)